# assigning values to template types by using literals

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

Is there any other way to assign values to template class members in constructors, other than using explicit initialization for fundamental types or casting?

```
template <class T>
struct A
{
public:
   T member;

   A() :member(T()) // or :member(static_cast<T>(1.0f))
   {}
};
```

I want to assign a value of 1.0 to `member` in the constructor. Can I do this without casting?

Comment: How can you assign `1.0` to any T without casting? You are going from one type to another; that's casting by definition.

Comment: @PeterAlexander Well, if you think about it, there could be something such as 1.0T instead of 1.0f or someth, in theory you can avoid a cast.

Comment: That depends what `T` could be. If it can only be primitive integral or floating point types then just use `1` and it will be interpreted as the correct value during compilation.

Comment: @PeterAlexander "_You are going from one type to another; that's casting by definition._" No, it's a conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use an integer, which can be implicitly converted to any numeric type:

```
template <class T>
struct A
{
public:
   T member;

   A() : member(1)
   {}
};

int main()
{
  A<int> a1;
  A<double> a2;
  A<float> a3; 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: hmm, cool, but what if I wanted to assign 1.5 for example? Isn't it possible without conversion? (ofc it would have to be precompiled but the point is to avoid a cast at run-time). EDIT: wait, templates don't get precompiled do they? hmm...

Comment: Well it doesn't matter it gets compiled depending on how you use it in your project, so in theory it should be possible to avoid a conversion at run-time.

Comment: If you want to assign 1.5 you will need to use an explicit cast, which as you have implemented in your question will be done at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with this:

```
A() :member(1)
{}
```

Comment: Won't that give a warning if T is int or float?